# Instagram instafeed Image rotator/Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instagram, rotator

This is my first post on StackOverflow and might I say, what a great and helpful resource this is. I have been able to find many answers to my questions and hope to do the same with this one. On to the issue at hand... I am currently using the instafeed.js (http://instafeedjs.com/) script to pull in images from instagram and display them on my site.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have 9 items display, then if I hit the "next" button, it would replace the current 9 images and load the next 9 images and, if the "previous" button is clicked it would go back and show the previous 9 images.

Currently it only renders one image thumb that scrolls through 9 images then stops. Swapping only the one image at a time. A sample of the current working code with only 1 image displaying can be found here - http://codepen.io/stevenschobert/pen/iHxfw

Here is my JavaScript for the instafeed call:

```
            var count = 1;              
            var feed;
            feed = new Instafeed({
              clientId: '68be8b63013048ff81bb4ac8b02b606e',
              limit: 9,
              resolution: 'standard_resolution',
              template: '<a href="{{image}}" rel="lightbox"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>',
              mock: true,
              after: function () {
                    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
                    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
                      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
                      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
                      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
                      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
                      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
                      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
                      $(image).addClass('animated fadeInUp pic-'+count++);
                    });
                  },
              custom: {
                images: [],
                currentImage: 0,
                showImage: function () {
                  var result, image;
                  image = this.options.custom.images[this.options.custom.currentImage];
                  result = this._makeTemplate(this.options.template, {
                    model: image,
                    id: image.id,
                    link: image.link,
                    image: image.images[this.options.resolution].url,
                    caption: this._getObjectProperty(image, 'caption.text'),
                    likes: image.likes.count,
                    comments: image.comments.count,
                    location: this._getObjectProperty(image, 'location.name')
                  });
                  $("#instafeed").html(result);
                }
              },
              success: function (data) {
                this.options.custom.images = data.data; 
                this.options.custom.showImage.call(this);
              }
            });
            feed.run();

            $(".next").click(function () {
              var length, current;
              current = feed.options.custom.currentImage;
              length = feed.options.custom.images.length;
              if (current < length - 1) {
                feed.options.custom.currentImage++;
                feed.options.custom.showImage.call(feed);
              }
            });

            $(".prev").click(function () {
              var length, current;
              current = feed.options.custom.currentImage;
              length = feed.options.custom.images.length;
              if (current > 0) {
                feed.options.custom.currentImage--
                feed.options.custom.showImage.call(feed);
              }
            });
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>                             
                            <div class="controls">
                              <div class="prev">&lt;- prev</div>
                              <div class="next">next -&gt;</div>
                            </div>
```

The Instafeed.js code:

```
(function() { var Instafeed, root; Instafeed = (function() {

function Instafeed(params) {
  var option, value;
  this.options = {
    target: 'instafeed',
    get: 'popular',
    resolution: 'thumbnail',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    links: true,
    limit: 15,
    mock: false
  };
  if (typeof params === 'object') {
    for (option in params) {
      value = params[option];
      this.options[option] = value;
    }
  }
  this.unique = this._genKey();
}

Instafeed.prototype.run = function() {
  var header, instanceName, script;
  if (typeof this.options.clientId !== 'string') {
    if (typeof this.options.accessToken !== 'string') {
      throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");
    }
  }
  if (typeof this.options.accessToken !== 'string') {
    if (typeof this.options.clientId !== 'string') {
      throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");
    }
  }
  if ((this.options.before != null) && typeof this.options.before === 'function') {
    this.options.before.call(this);
  }
  if (typeof document !== "undefined" && document !== null) {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'instafeed-fetcher';
    script.src = this._buildUrl();
    header = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    header[0].appendChild(script);
    instanceName = "instafeedCache" + this.unique;
    window[instanceName] = new Instafeed(this.options);
    window[instanceName].unique = this.unique;
  }
  return true;
};

Instafeed.prototype.parse = function(response) {
  var anchor, fragment, header, htmlString, image, imageString, images, img, instanceName, reverse, sortSettings, _i, _j, _len, _len1;
  if (typeof response !== 'object') {
    if ((this.options.error != null) && typeof this.options.error === 'function') {
      this.options.error.call(this, 'Invalid JSON data');
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid JSON response');
    }
  }
  if (response.meta.code !== 200) {
    if ((this.options.error != null) && typeof this.options.error === 'function') {
      this.options.error.call(this, response.meta.error_message);
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Error from Instagram: " + response.meta.error_message);
    }
  }
  if (response.data.length === 0) {
    if ((this.options.error != null) && typeof this.options.error === 'function') {
      this.options.error.call(this, 'No images were returned from Instagram');
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Error('No images were returned from Instagram');
    }
  }
  if ((this.options.success != null) && typeof this.options.success === 'function') {
    this.options.success.call(this, response);
  }
  if (this.options.sortBy !== 'most-recent') {
    if (this.options.sortBy === 'random') {
      sortSettings = ['', 'random'];
    } else {
      sortSettings = this.options.sortBy.split('-');
    }
    reverse = sortSettings[0] === 'least' ? true : false;
    switch (sortSettings[1]) {
      case 'random':
        response.data.sort(function() {
          return 0.5 - Math.random();
        });
        break;
      case 'recent':
        response.data = this._sortBy(response.data, 'created_time', reverse);
        break;
      case 'liked':
        response.data = this._sortBy(response.data, 'likes.count', reverse);
        break;
      case 'commented':
        response.data = this._sortBy(response.data, 'comments.count', reverse);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("Invalid option for sortBy: '" + this.options.sortBy + "'.");
    }
  }
  if ((typeof document !== "undefined" && document !== null) && this.options.mock === false) {
    document.getElementById(this.options.target).innerHTML = '';
    images = response.data;
    if (images.length > this.options.limit) {
      images = images.slice(0, this.options.limit + 1 || 9e9);
    }
    if ((this.options.template != null) && typeof this.options.template === 'string') {
      htmlString = '';
      imageString = '';
      for (_i = 0, _len = images.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        image = images[_i];
        imageString = this._makeTemplate(this.options.template, {
          model: image,
          id: image.id,
          link: image.link,
          image: image.images[this.options.resolution].url,
          caption: this._getObjectProperty(image, 'caption.text'),
          likes: image.likes.count,
          comments: image.comments.count,
          location: this._getObjectProperty(image, 'location.name')
        });
        htmlString += imageString;
      }
      document.getElementById(this.options.target).innerHTML = htmlString;
    } else {
      fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
      for (_j = 0, _len1 = images.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
        image = images[_j];
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = image.images[this.options.resolution].url;
        if (this.options.links === true) {
          anchor = document.createElement('a');
          anchor.href = image.images['standard_resolution'].url;
          anchor.rel = "lightbox";
          anchor.appendChild(img);
          fragment.appendChild(anchor);
        } else {
          fragment.appendChild(img);
        }
      }
      document.getElementById(this.options.target).appendChild(fragment);
    }
    header = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    header.removeChild(document.getElementById('instafeed-fetcher'));
    instanceName = "instafeedCache" + this.unique;
    delete window[instanceName];
  }
  if ((this.options.after != null) && typeof this.options.after === 'function') {
    this.options.after.call(this);
  }
  return true;
};

Instafeed.prototype._buildUrl = function() {
  var base, endpoint, final;
  base = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";
  switch (this.options.get) {
    case "popular":
      endpoint = "media/popular";
      break;
    case "tagged":
      if (typeof this.options.tagName !== 'string') {
        throw new Error("No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.");
      }
      endpoint = "tags/" + this.options.tagName + "/media/recent";
      break;
    case "location":
      if (typeof this.options.locationId !== 'number') {
        throw new Error("No location specified. Use the 'locationId' option.");
      }
      endpoint = "locations/" + this.options.locationId + "/media/recent";
      break;
    case "user":
      if (typeof this.options.userId !== 'number') {
        throw new Error("No user specified. Use the 'userId' option.");
      }
      if (typeof this.options.accessToken !== 'string') {
        throw new Error("No access token. Use the 'accessToken' option.");
      }
      endpoint = "users/" + this.options.userId + "/media/recent";
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error("Invalid option for get: '" + this.options.get + "'.");
  }
  final = "" + base + "/" + endpoint;
  if (this.options.accessToken != null) {
    final += "?access_token=" + this.options.accessToken;
  } else {
    final += "?client_id=" + this.options.clientId;
  }
  final += "&count=" + this.options.limit;
  final += "&callback=instafeedCache" + this.unique + ".parse";
  return final;
};

Instafeed.prototype._genKey = function() {
  var S4;
  S4 = function() {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
  };
  return "" + (S4()) + (S4()) + (S4()) + (S4());
};

Instafeed.prototype._makeTemplate = function(template, data) {
  var output, pattern, varName, varValue, _ref;
  pattern = /(?:\{{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\}{2})/;
  output = template;
  while (pattern.test(output)) {
    varName = output.match(pattern)[1];
    varValue = (_ref = this._getObjectProperty(data, varName)) != null ? _ref : '';
    output = output.replace(pattern, "" + varValue);
  }
  return output;
};

Instafeed.prototype._getObjectProperty = function(object, property) {
  var piece, pieces;
  property = property.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1');
  pieces = property.split('.');
  while (pieces.length) {
    piece = pieces.shift();
    if ((object != null) && piece in object) {
      object = object[piece];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return object;
};

Instafeed.prototype._sortBy = function(data, property, reverse) {
  var sorter;
  sorter = function(a, b) {
    var valueA, valueB;
    valueA = this._getObjectProperty(a, property);
    valueB = this._getObjectProperty(b, property);
    if (reverse) {
      if (valueA > valueB) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (valueA < valueB) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  };
  data.sort(sorter.bind(this));
  return data;
};

return Instafeed;})(); root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : window; root.Instafeed = Instafeed;}).call(this);
```

Any help with this issue would be **GREATLY** appreciated.

Thank You,

Jason

Comment: Jason, if I am not mistaken about your problem, then you want to get some images from Instagram and then customize their display method, rotating them and so on. So my question is: Can we leave Instagram and instafeed.js out of the story and solve only the rotation of the pictures? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, I am open to other options, methods, and suggestions. I do need it to pull photos from instagram though. I'm currently looking at this alternative since I'm running Wordpress http://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-instagram/

Comment: Jason, I was talking about my opinion that you are taking the pictures from whatever source you are taking them from (currently Instagram with instafeed.js), but I think that is irrelevant from the problem's perspective, because we have a problem with the way the pictures are displayed, but we do not have a problem with Instagram and instafeed.js, as you successfully loaded the pictures. Is that correct? Can we focus only on the problem of image rotation on client-side? If so, then please take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: The issue is not a css transformation/animation. All i'm trying to accomplish is to show 9 thumbnails rather than just 1 thumbnail. Then, slide through those 9 thumbnails when hitting the next or previous buttons. Like an instagram thumbnail slider. Please look at this link - http://codepen.io/stevenschobert/pen/iHxfw

Comment: Anyone with more information regarding pagination and InstafeedJS? I'm strugling with this script, since it only shows one and one image. Also tried modyfying the parameters to suit my needs, but without any luck. If anyone can help me or pinpoint me in the right direction, I would be happy. Unfortunately I cannot paste my code here since I'm on the go atm.